# Jssor - how to add slides dynamically?

Tags: jssor

I have to put image loading at client side, which is basically right after browser finishes requesting a page, an ajax call is triggered to load list of images, then slides are added into sider container. Number of photos is not known after that ajax call.

I tried building html text of slides, and assign into slider container, then trigger the slider-starter. But the slider doesn't show properly.

Thanks a lot for any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing in a right way.
All you need is to check slides (you added dynamically) are correct or not.

To check html created dynamically, you can copy it out and test it in a standalone html file to see if the slider works.

Comment: I checked carefully the html text of slides but still can not make it work. I changed to another way: create dummy slides - this time number of slides are fixed, then js script will change src attribute of image and thumb, but only images works meaning correct images are shown. Thumbs don't work, dummy thumbs are not changed to real thumbs

Comment: please post your code (both before geneate and after generate javascript + html) here

Comment: I'v found out the reason: I put trigger of the slider start outside success function of ajax call, meaning the slider is started before the html text assigned to slides container. My stuff is good now. Thank you

Comment: would be nice to share sample code, so others don't have to ask the same question.

Comment: Hi Jssor. Do you know of any examples of loading jssor with ajax on a button click?

Comment: @Ben can you provide us the working sample? I also want to add slides dynamically. its urgent i need to demonstrate by Monday 25th May 2015.

Comment: @michaelhanon, sorry that I saw your comment late, anyway I post my answer below

Comment: @Ben can you provide the full script? and where you embed the part above?

Answer (score 5):

I post what I did here in case it's helpful for someone:

```
//function to start the slider    
jssor_slider1_starter = function (containerId) {
                    var options = {
                        $AutoPlay: false,
                        $SlideDuration: 800,
                        $FillMode: 2,
                        $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
                            $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,
                            $ChanceToShow: 2,

                            $Lanes: 1,
                            $SpacingX: 14,
                            $SpacingY: 12,
                            $Cols: 6,
                            $Align: 156,
                            $Orientation: 2
                        }
                    };

                    var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(containerId, options);
                };
//Ajax function to start the slider after loading the 'content' of slider
//getImgUrl is the url of page returning urls of images contained in slider. Format of response can be whatever as long as you can parse it, my sample is [[[url1,url2..]]]   
 $.ajax({
                    url:getImgUrl,
                    success:function(data){
                        var imgurls_str=data.substring(data.indexOf('[[[')+3,data.indexOf(']]]'));
                        var imgurls=imgurls_str.split(',');
                        var imgHtmls='';
                        for(var i=0;i<imgurls.length;++i){
                            imgHtmls+='<div><img u="image" src="'+imgurls[i]+'" /><img u="thumb" src="'+imgurls[i]+'" /></div>';
                        }
                        $("#slides").html(imgHtmls);
                        jssor_slider1_starter('slider1_container');
                    }
                });
```

Comment: In the answer above, images are added all at once, as imgHtmls hold all the images, my question is how can I add image 1 at a time and refresh the slider?

Comment: @Ben can you provide the full script? and where you embed the part above?